# Open the modal in handlebar page, if the variable contains any value, i want to write jquery code if there is value and it returns true

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, handlebars.js

This is index.js from where the "create" page is rendered if `session` is set, else "first" page is rendered with a `openloginmodal` variable with `no` as the value.

Index.js

```
 app.get('/create',function(req,res){
  if (req.session.fullname!=null)
   {
    res.render('create',{Email:req.session.fullname,firstName:'Nayan',lastName:'Patel',layout:false});
   }
 else
  {
    res.render('first',{openloginmodal:"no",layout:false});
 }
});
```

first.handlebars

Here I am checking whether the `openloginmodal` contains any value or not. If it contains any value, I want to open the modal automatically. 
But it is not working, please help me to do this.
Thanks in advance.

```
{{#if openloginmodal}} 
<script type="text/javascript">$("#myModal").modal('show');</script>{{/if}}

<!-- Login modal start here-->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="loginmodal-container">
      <h1>Login to Your Account</h1><br>
      <form action="/login" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="user[email]" placeholder="Email">
      <input type="password" name="user[pass]" placeholder="Password">
      <input type="submit" name="login" class="login loginmodal-submit" value="Login">
      </form>

      <div class="login-help">
      <a href="#">Register</a> - <a href="#">Forgot Password</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The browser is going to execute the code within the script tag *before* it parses the Login Modal. So `$('#myModal')` is *always* going to be an empty jQuery collection. You need to either move the script to below the Login Modal HTML *or* wrap your code in a callback that will execute only once the document has loaded. See: https://api.jquery.com/ready/

```
{{#if openloginmodal}}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#myModal").modal('show');
        });
    </script>
{{/if}}
```